# Why am I getting an ambiguous column in my PG on conflict insert?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

Here is my query:

```
insert into zoning_algorithm_value (algorithm_value_id, value, zoning_id)
values (
           61,
           21,
           7321
       )
on conflict(algorithm_value_id)
    DO
        update set value = 21 where zoning_id = 7321 and algorithm_value_id = 61;
```

I am only referencing one table.  Here is the error I am getting.

> [42702] ERROR: column reference "zoning_id" is ambiguous

How can it be ambiguous when there is only one table and one column with that name?  How do I make this upsert work?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify the table name or `EXCLUDED` to precede the fields in the `WHERE` clause.

For example, if you only want to update `value` when the "new" `zoning_id` and `algorithm_value_id` are 7321 and 61, respectively:

```
insert into zoning_algorithm_value (algorithm_value_id, value, zoning_id)
values (61, 21, 7321)
on conflict(algorithm_value_id)
    DO
        update set value = 21 where EXCLUDED.zoning_id = 7321 and EXCLUDED.algorithm_value_id = 61;
```

If you instead want the `WHERE` to reference the "existing" record values, use the table name.